# redirect to 404 if flask form data has not been submitted

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a flask form on my index page. I also have a separate page that will just say "thanks" if the user submits data via the form, the user will be redirected here after hitting submit on the form.

The url for this redirected page can always be accessed by typing /thanks into the browser. I would like to block access to this url, or redirect to a 404 page (which I have created) if the form contains no data. I am wondering how I can achieve this?

Here is my code for my index page route. On loading the form is available:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    email = None
    postcode = None
    form = InputForm()
    # validate form
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        email = form.email.data
        postcode = form.postcode.data
        form.email.data = ''
        form.postcode.data = ''
        return redirect(url_for('thanks'))
    return render_template(
        "index.html",
        email = email,
        postcode = postcode,
        form = form
        )
```

Here is my code for my redirect route, after the form is submitted. This is the route I want to block if the form has not been submitted, or if the data in the form is None.

```
@app.route('/thanks')
def thanks():
    return 'Thanks for submitting data via the form!'
```

Here is my 404 route - for reference.

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template("404.html"), 404
```

Comment: if you return the "thanks" content instead of the `return redirect(url_for('thanks'))` you will have the same effect, just the URL will not be: "<domain>/thanks". If this is not acceptable to you, perhaps you can redirect to `/thanks?submit=true`, i.e add a variable that will differentiate this redirect from a regular visit of a user to page "/thanks", and modify the thanks method to print only if the GET variable is there. Ofc, if user visits /thanks?submit=true, he will still see the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.One quick and dirty way is to have a global variable which you set when you process your submit. You check for this variable within thanks and if not present you raise your 404 error i.e. something like

```
    wasRedirected = False

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
       global wasRedirected
 
       if form.validate_on_submit():
          wasRedirected = True
          .........
          return redirect(url_for('thanks'))
    

    @app.route('/thanks')
    def thanks():
        global wasRedirected
        # If wasRedirected is true, it means it was set during a form submit
        if wasRedirected:
            wasRedirected = False
            return 'Thanks for submitting data via the form!'
        else:
           # raise your 404 error
```

2. You can also check out [request.referrer](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.referrer) to see if it will work here (i.e. see if the referrer when you do a redirect will be different from when you access the route directly).